# What are the default SSL/TLS protocols enabled or disabled in various Windows server environments?

Tags: windows, ssl

It's easy to find guides to enable or disable specific SSL/TLS protocols such as this [one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/manage-ssl-protocols-in-ad-fs) or this other [one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings).

However, what are the default secure channel protocol(s) enabled or disabled for each version of Windows? Especially for servers.

I mean the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols` key is always empty so what does that mean about those protocols for each OS version?

For example, I know in 2008R2 you need to add values to enable TLS1.2 but that's not necessary in Windows 2016 because it's enabled by default. However, in both OS that registry key is empty by default... So that makes it quite hard to audit those protocol in a corporate environment!

Any clear answer or direction to detailed documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this answer varies by patch level in addition to major OS version.